# How to search a long value in Arraylist?

Tags: java

I want to search for a phone number in an array list. The phone number is a `long` value. How to do so?
When I do that using `contains()` it throws an error.

I have tried using `contains()` method but it throws an error.

```
public boolean removeContact(long phoneNumber)
{
    for(int i=0;i<phoneBook.size();i++)
    {
        if(phoneBook.get(i).getPhoneNumber().contains(phoneNumber))
        {
            phoneBook.remove(i);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

When I compile the code it shows an error that long cannot be dereferenced

Comment: *"The phone number is a long value."* Phone numbers aren't (despite the common term) numbrers, it would be very strange to store one in a `long`.

Comment: In the problem itself, it is mentioned to take phone number as long

Comment: How is `phoneBook` initialized? Why would you use `contains` (a `String` method for looking for substring matches)? *"When I compile the code it shows an error that long cannot be dereferenced"* Always quote **exact** error messages (using copy and paste).

Comment: Please re-read that first comment.

Comment: ./PhoneBook.java:25: error: long cannot be dereferenced
     if(phoneBook.get(i).getPhoneNumber().contains(phoneNumber))

Comment: what is the `getPhoneNumber()`

Comment: how deep you must go in order to get a number? `phonebook.get(i).getPhoneNumber().contains(phoneNumber)` seems like a lot of deep sea. Also, are you trying to get a `longValue()` from the primitive long?

Comment: Please use the [edit](/posts/56629105/edit) link to add details / clarification to the question, rather than comments.

Comment: @FerasAlSous getPhoneNumber() is a getter method in a class Contact.

Comment: You cannot use .contains() on a primitive long, that's the reason of the error. getPhoneNumber() returns a long of primitive type

Answer (score 3):

From the error, it's clear that `getPhoneNumber` returns a `long`. So you'd just use `==`:

```
if(phoneBook.get(i).getPhoneNumber() == phoneNumber)
```

---

But as I said [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56629105/how-to-search-a-long-value-in-arraylist/56629193#comment99830099_56629105), `long` isn't the right data type for storing phone numbers. Phone numbers are textual data. You can't store `(415) 555-1234 ext 34` in a `long`.

Answer (score 1):

a much shorter solution since you are using an arraylist:

```
public boolean removeContact(long phoneNumber)
{
    Long number = new Long(phoneNumber);
    if(phoneBook.contains(number){
        phoneBook.remove(phoneBook.indexOf(number));
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: "much shorter" is exagerrated, its a for loop shorter

Comment: I'd upvote it if you fix that double Long creation : )

Comment: fixed the double long creation :D

Comment: simple and clean! it could as well be optimized using a hashset instead of a list, but that's not in the question : )